# How to Store Logged Company Id Per User Session in Asp.Net MVC 5 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, cookies

I have a login view which accepts a CompanyId also along with username and password. Once Logged in This company Id will be used to throughout the user session to filter data from the database.

What is the right way to achieve this? I also want this company Id to be stored along with the username and password in the cookies so that even if the user closes the browser and open again the company Id is persisted. or need a mechanism even if the user logged in by default by cookies as soon as it finds the company id is empty then user must be redirected to the login page.

Please help....
Noufal

Answer (score 2):

The right workflow could be:

1. Login only with user name and password
2. Get users company Id from the database (the user should enter companyId during registration process)
3. store users email in the authentication cookie (this will be the unique user identifier)
4. Load the companyId from DB on Application_PostAuthenticateRequest event in global asax and extend the current principal (Thread.CurrentPrincipal, HttpContext.Current.User) with this information.

Comment: Thank you so much MajoB. My scenario is little different I have nine legacy databases which shares same schema i.e. one database per company. Users are stored seperately in NetSqlAzman database. User must be able to select the company (database) during the login process and this company id will be used to identify the correct database which will be used throughout session unless user logs out and choose another one. Please extend your answer with this scenario. And also would like to know more about your 4th point specially how to extend current principal with the company Id. Thanks in Advance